# Wordpress custom image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need to use custom image field in wp plugin, everything works fine with upload/set function but have problem, when changing image:
Problem:
When i already have a image and need to replace i pick up new image from media library and submit, old one image stay visible so i have two images in view.

I asume that problem is with select function and append part, obviously i'm using wrong logic here, bellow are jquery+html of my code and screenshot of problem:

Problem(two images):
First one should replaced with new selection image (second image)

[Two images screenshot](http://pokit.org/get/?75a2d4af88bfeedddae7b01278efb90c.png)

This is my code:

```
$('#btn-upload-image').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var button = $(this);
        var figure = button.siblings("figure");

        var custom_uploader = wp.media({
                title: 'Insert image',
                library: { type : 'image' },
                button: { text: 'Use this image' },
                id: 'library-' + (Math.random() * 10),
                multiple: false
            }).on('select', function() {
                var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                figure.append( $('<img/>', { 'src': attachment.url }) );
                inputImage.val(attachment.url);
                inputImageId.val(attachment.id);
        })
        .open();
    });
```

and html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Image</label>
                        <figure></figure>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-upload-image">Upload Image</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="image" id="input-image" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="input-image-id" />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

`figure.append( $('<img/>', { 'src': attachment.url }) );`

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts content at the end of the target element, maintaining existing content in place. What you want in this case is to replace whatever is in there with new content (the new image), so:

`figure.html( $('<img/>', { 'src': attachment.url }) );`

[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) replaces any content that was in the targeted element(s) with the new one.

Hope that helps!